# draw the altitude of a triangle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I want to draw a line that signifies the altitude of a triangle.  I know all 3 points of the circle (a, b, c).  I want to draw the altitude through a.

I have the following functions to work out the perpendicular gradient of bc

```
gradient = function(a, b) {  
  return b.y - a.y / b.x - a.x;
};

perpendicularGradient = function (a, b) {
  return -1 / gradient(a, b);
};
```

I can now get the equation of the line using `y = mx + c` for line of a with a perpendicular slope of bc and I can work out the y intercept.

```
function perpendicularLine(vertex, a, b) {
  // b = y - m * x
  var slope = perpendicularGradient(a, b),
      yIntercept = (- slope * vertex.x) + vertex.y;

  //how do I find the coordinates of the point on bc to draw a line from vertex
}
```

I don't know what to do next, i.e. how do I find the coordinates of the point on bc to join the line from a.

From googling about, I know I could use vectors but I have not covered that yet on my maths course and I would prefer to use the equation of a line.

Comment: That should be `(b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x)` - please see [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). And what will you do if `b.x == a.x`?

Comment: I know there are exceptions for horizontal lines but this is really a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, after you have your yIntercept and the slope of the perpendicular line, you need to construct a system of 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns (x0, y0) from the 2 line equations (bc line and line passing through a). The solution to this system is your intersection point along the bc line.

Comment: so I need to get both equations in the format of Ax + bx = c?

Comment: There's a multitude of ways, but yes, you can use ax + by = c. If you have one of the equations in y = slope*x + yIntercept, you can just substitute y in the other equation.

Comment: I have the points and their y intercepts

Say I have the point (6, 18) and y intercept of 27 then how does that translate into ax + by = c

is it 

6 + 18 = 27

Or is it 6 + 18 = -27

Comment: In your code example, you actually have the slope and the y intercept, so: y = slope * x + yIntercept then becomes -slope*x + y = yIntercept.

If you just have the intercept and a random point along the line, then again following the math: 18 = slope * 6 + 27, and you can derive your slope to be - 3/2. Your line equation would then be y =-3/2 * x + 27 and if you want this in Ax + By = C form, it would be 3x + 2y = 54

Answer (score 0):

Let a point `p` along `bc`, given by the vector equation `p = b + t bc`, where `t` is a parameter. You express orthogonality of the altitude and the base by

```
ap.bc = 0, or (ab + t bc) bc = 0.
```

This gives

```
t = -ab.bc/bc²
```

which allows you to compute `p`.